# Maintain text color when copying from html to doc/docx file

Tags: html, css, formatting, docx

I produce this html code to the page:

```
<p style="font-size: 13.33px">Probability: <a id="low" style="font-size: 13.33px; color: #70ad47"><b>Low</b></a></p>
<p style="font-size: 13.33px">Severity: <a id="medium" style="font-size: 13.33px; color: #ffc000"><b>Medium</b></a></p>
<p style="font-size: 13.33px"><b>Overall Risk:</b> <a id="high" style="font-size: 13.33px; color: #ff0000"><b>High</b></a></p>
```

But when I copy it directly from the web page to a docx file, it comes out with no color:

[image: copied to docx file]

How can I keep the color formatting when copying?

Comment: See the following: https://superuser.com/questions/547773/how-do-i-copy-paste-website-content-with-formatting

Comment: How come i can copy the example texts from w3schools to a word document with color though?

Answer (score 0):

Actually  the copy command from the browser captures the HTML part mostly and it can probably work with doing      ctrl + shift + v     rather than just
ctrl + v    but I don't guarantee it will work because copy-paste doesn't capture the advanced CSS

Comment: How come i can copy the example texts from w3schools to a word document with color without any special paste?